# Como hacer que el mapeo de entidades a partir de la base de datos de JPA reconozca el tipo de dato de la Base de datos con

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa, netbeans-8.2, sql-server-2012

Estoy usando Netbeans 8.2 proyecto web clases Entidad a partir de una Base de Datos, mapeo con JPA una base de datos SQL server2012 de Microsoft. en un inicio me mapeo con los tipos de datos como Date, Image... y demas. De lujo, asi: 
[image: Bien mapeado con jpa]
 Pero luego de hacer unas modificaciones(un par de campos en tablas) ya no mapea igual ahora los pone como String, asi:
[image: Mal mapeado con jpa]
 y me frego pues son muchas tablas, que tienen fechas para auditar cuando se modifico y creo, en fin.

Por favor espero alguien me ayude y me diga como se hace para que el mapeo del JPA me permita reconocer los tipos de datos de la base de datos, y como genero en un inicio y porque genera ahora como String.
Me ha dificultado usar un  pues solo me permite pasar las fechas ni con el formato modificado, solo como string.

Comment: ¿Generaste automáticamente las entidades a partir de las tablas con Netbeans? ¿Has intentado cambiar la entidad manualmente (cambiandole el tipo de String a Date?

Comment: los cambie a mano en una tabla, pero me da errores pues, no solo me da problemas en el campo Date sino también en las relaciones, por ejemplo (cuando tengo una relación de un Padre a muchos Hijos, no me instancia con la clase padre, que seria lo correcto, sino solo el id del padre como  un dato String). me complico mucho, pero la verdad me toco actualizar el JDK 1.8.0_92, ligar el Netbeans 8.2 a la nueva version JDK 1.8.0_181-b13 y me mapeo bien, no pude encontrar la solución, pero la nueva instalación no tiene este error y uso en Fedora 27 para el desarrollo. Espero a nadie mas le pase.